# Why is excel reopening after restart pc

Tags: excel, vb.net, button

I don't see what's wrong in my code.

The intention is to automatically adjust the button text to cell "B2" (Excel sheet 1). I have buttons from 2 to 37. Maybe someone has a different code to do this faster?

```
    Dim oExcelApp As New Excel.Application
    'define variable - type of Workbook
    Dim oExcelBook As Excel.Workbook
    'define variable - type of Worksheet
    Dim oExcelSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sheetNumber As Integer = 1 '1-based array
    Dim sData As String = ""
    Dim fileNameAndPath As String = TextBox1.Text

    Try
        '    ''open Workbook
        oExcelBook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileNameAndPath)
        '    ''get Workshhet
        oExcelSheet = CType(oExcelBook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)


        Dim Btn2Range As String = "B2"
        sData = oExcelSheet.Range(Btn2Range).Value.ToString()
        Button2.Text = sData

    Catch exp As COMException
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message)
        oExcelBook.Close()
    Catch exp As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Message)
        oExcelBook.Close()
    End Try
    oExcelBook.Close(fileNameAndPath)
    oExcelApp.Quit()

End Sub
```

Comment: So, you just want to rretrieve cell `B2` from `sheet1` and use the value for `Button2.Text`, right?

Comment: yes indeed, this should be done automatically when loading the form so that the user can edit the button text via the excel sheet. button 2 = B2, button 3 = B3 etc

Comment: Are you saying that Excel reopens?  When you are calling close, what happens when you do this `oExcelBook.Close(True, fileNameAndPath)` where True is telling it to save changes.

Comment: The 1st argument to [WorkBook.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close) is the `SaveChanges` (true/false) not `FileName`.

Comment: the same result, after reboot pc excel opens a blank sheet

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function

```
Function getValueFromFile(path As String, file As String, sheet As String, row As Long, column As Long) As String

    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim arg As String
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!R" & row.ToString & "C" & column.ToString

    'Run XL4-Macro
    getValueFromFile = xlApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
    xlApp.Quit()
End Function
```

A test could look like that

```
Sub Main()
    Dim res As String
    res = getValueFromFile("C:\TMP\XL\", "xlFile.xlsx", "Sheet1", 2, 2)
    Console.Write("Result:  ")
    Console.WriteLine(res)
    Console.Write("Press key ...")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

**Update:** I applied the function to the code you posted

```
' Add this at the top of your code
    Imports System.IO

        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            Dim fileNameAndPath As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim sData As String = ""
    
    
            Dim fileName As String
            Dim filePath As String
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileNameAndPath)
            filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNameAndPath)
    
    
            Try
                'Dim Btn2Range As String = "B2"
                sData = getValueFromFile(filePath & "\", fileName, "Sheet1", 2, 2)
                'sData = oExcelSheet.Range(Btn2Range).Value.ToString()
                Button2.Text = sData
    
    
            Catch exp As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message)
    
            End Try
        End Sub
        Function getValueFromFile(path As String, file As String, sheet As String, row As Long, column As Long) As String
    
            Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
            Dim arg As String
            arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!R" & row.ToString & "C" & column.ToString
    
            'Run XL4-Macro
            getValueFromFile = xlApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
            xlApp.Quit()
        End Function
```

Comment: this is a bit too complicated for a novice like me :-)

Comment: What is too complicated for you?

Comment: What it all means. Is it ok for you if i upload my project?

Comment: Thx in advance. The code works but now the command button text only changes when you click on it and excel still opens blank sheets after restarting the pc. This only happens when I have clicked on the command button.

Comment: _the command button text only changes when you click on it_  Yes, that's the way how it is programmed _excel still opens blank sheets after restarting the pc. This only happens when I have clicked on the command button._ Sorry, I do not have an explnation for that. This is not happening at my PC.

Comment: strange that excel opens this with me. Can I do this other via access database that I already use in the project (Database11)?

Comment: The question is quite broad but of course you can also retrieve data from a access database. But you should post another question for that. Your original post was about another topic